# Permutating through the array of chars

Tags: java, arrays, unique, combinations

Suppose you need to discover all possible permutations of 'n' distinct characters, say 'a', 'b', 'c'.  Can you suggest an algorithm I can use to get this done?  Generally speaking, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 'Perms' be the collection of permutations found, and 'Used' be a list of the characters currently selected.

To find permutations of n chars from a set S:

1. If n = 0, then Used is a permutation.  Add it to Perms and return.
2. For each char C in S:

   1. Remove C from S and append (or push) it to U.
   2. Find permutations of n-1 chars from S.
   3. Remove the end of (or pop) U and add C to S.

When you've returned from finding permutations of n chars, Perms contains all the possible permutations.

Note, this is all done using sets and lists.  There are lighter-weight alternatives, but these structures make the steps more straightforward, so i used them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&sort=&id=71).